# Create custom 'Tab Style Selector' using api

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata, custom

I have two questions relating to 'Tab style selector' or `<motif>`.

1. I am trying to create a customTab using api and in doing so I need to put in what motif I want to use. For example, it could be 'Custom53: Bell'. However, there are numerous such motifs available and each has a number associated with it. Is there a list available for the same?
2. I know there is an option to create a custom 'Tab Style Selector' using ui. Is there any way to do the same using api?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 I have created a list of predefined motif available in salesforce ,However you can always create custom motif. Please upvote if this answers your first question.

```
Custom1:Heart
Custom2:Fan
Custom3:Sun
Custom4:Hexagon
Custom5:Leaf
Custom6:Triangle
Custom7:Square
Custom8:Diamond
Custom9:Lightning
Custom10:Moon
Custom11:Star
Custom12:Circle
Custom13:Box
Custom14:Hands
Custom15:People
Custom16:Bank
Custom17:Sack
Custom18:Form
Custom19:Wrench
Custom20:Airplane
Custom21:Computer
Custom22:Telephone
Custom23:Envelope
Custom24:Building
Custom25:Alarmclock
Custom26:Flag
Custom27:Laptop
Custom28:Cellphone
Custom29:PDA
Custom30:Radardish
Custom31:Car
Custom32:Factory
Custom33:Desk
Custom34:Insect
Custom35:Microphone
Custom36:Train
Custom37:Bridge
Custom38:Camera
Custom39:Telescope
Custom40:Creditcard
Custom41:Cash
Custom42:Treasurechest
Custom43:Jewel
Custom44:Hammer
Custom45:Ticket
Custom46:Stamp
Custom47:Knight
Custom48:Trophy
Custom49:CD/DVD
Custom50:Bigtop
Custom51:Apple
Custom52:Balls
Custom53:Bell
Custom54:Boat
Custom55:Books
Custom56:Bottle
Custom57:BuildingBlock
Custom58:Caduceus
Custom59:Can
Custom60:Umbrella
Custom61:Castle
Custom62:Chalkboard
Custom63:Chip
Custom64:Compass
Custom65:Cup
Custom66:Dice
Custom67:Gears
Custom68:Globe
Custom69:Guitar
Custom70:Handsaw
Custom71:Headset
Custom72:Helicopter
Custom73:HighwaySign
Custom74:HotAirBalloon
Custom75:IPPhone
Custom76:Keys
Custom77:Locked
Custom78:Map
Custom79:MeasuringTape
Custom80:Motorcycle
Custom81:MusicalNote
Custom82:Whistle
Custom83:Pencil
Custom84:Presenter
Custom85:RealEstateSign
Custom86:RedCross
Custom87:Safe
Custom88:Sailboat
Custom89:Saxophone
Custom90:Scales
Custom91:Shield
Custom92:Ship
Custom93:ShoppingCart
Custom94:Stethoscope
Custom95:Stopwatch
Custom96:StreetSign
Custom97:Thermometer
Custom98:Truck
Custom99:TVCRT
Custom100:TVWidescreen
```

2 You can create custom motif like this.

```
"motif": {

   "color": "8C004C",

   "largeIconUrl": "/img/icon/custom51_100/boat64.png",

   "mediumIconUrl": "/img/icon/custom51_100/boat32.png",

   "smallIconUrl": "/img/icon/custom51_100/boat16.png",

   "svgIconUrl": null

},
```

Please upvote if this Helps!!

Thanks,
Vikas

Comment: Thanks for the list of motifs. This helps a lot. But, I wanted to know, is the way of motif creation you mentioned api through, if yes could you provide more details, else let me know if it is possible to do via api.

Comment: @zen There is a class ConnectApi.Motif but i think this is specific to chatterAPI. I am not sure exactly how to use it.You can check following links:-[Link1] (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_connect_api.htm)
[Link 2](https://m.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_connectapi_output_motif.htm)